# How can I check to see when the next day starts in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

I'm trying to trigger an event when the next day starts (at 00:00:00).  I'm also using the local time zone, not UTC since triggering off of the UTC time will cause the next day to start early.  Here is how I'm getting the local time:

```
import pytz
import datetime

tz = pytz.timezone('America/Chicago') # Set the timezone

utc_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
local_time = (pytz.utc.localize(utc_time, is_dst=None).astimezone(tz))

if (local_time == datetime.timedelta(days=1)):
    *** My action starts here ***
```

But this doesn't seem to trigger at 00:00:00 local time.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: So first of all there is no loop here checking for the time to be 00:00:00. The chances of you running this and it getting to the equals 00:00:00 check to happen within a 1 second window is quite low. You would need to loop and update the local_time and then check if it is 00:00:00 very quickly. You only have a 1 second window. Also you are comparing a datetime object to a timedelta object which is wrong.

Comment: You compare time with time difference, that is, oranges and apples. Why would they ever be equal?

Comment: try ```if local_time.time().strftime('%H:%M:%S') == '00:00:00':``` but as i said, loop the check so you actually catch it for that 1 second the if statement is true

Comment: Just verified, this works.  I found a way to add this to an existing function, and then call it in a while loop that is always running.  This makes sense, but requires my code to process this exactly at 00:00:00.  I may try to find a way to broaden the window of time it uses to verify whether it is the next day, possibly by checking only the hour and minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for time delta 1 day, so if it starts at 15:43, delta +1 day will be 15:43 next day. Another thing is if you miss that time it will never trigger.
On your place i would use this:

```
import datetetime
from time import sleep
# get current day in month (we don't need anything else)
currentDay = datetime.datetime.now().day # datetime's now is localized
# watch for it to change
while (datetime.datetime.now().day == currentDay):
    sleep(1) # increase time if you don't need exactly at the midnight
print("Good midnight, today is...")
```

Answer (score 0):

How to do this without the datetime library:

```
cur = time.localtime()
# ...(time passes)
if cur[:3] != time.localtime()[:3]:
    print("It's a new day!")
```

How it works? `time.localtime()[:3]` is giving the first 3 values of `time.struct_time` comparing the year, month and  day.